# Is S Voice slow?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, s-voice

Is Svoice taking like atleast 10 seconds (sometimes more) to accept a command and reply (even if the reply is "I didnt catch that" ? Or is my device this slow?

Comment: or is your Internet slow?

Comment: Do you really want to know if S Voice is slow or do you want to know how it can be made faster?

Comment: @Flow I want to know if it is normal to take 10 seconds or more for S voice to react

Comment: @roxan My internet is not slow (I am using 2mbps broadband and it works fine)

Comment: I don't have SIII but lots of videos in Youtube shows that its very fast.

Comment: I have found it takes a long long time.. I believe that it is sending the audio to a converter first, which may take time. However, even with 4G and Wifi it's still slow.

Answer (score -1):

It's much slower than Siri with the same connection speeds. It is also less accurate.